# callback on associated has_many not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Seems like i’ve gone back to basics and am missing something… ..
I have two models User and Lists. User has many lists and lists belongs to User… When we remove the user from the list, i.e. the lists user_id == nil, we can’t seem to catch the update through a callback like after_update or after_commit.

```rb
class List < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :check_user
  belongs_to :user
  private
  def check_user
    binding.pry
    if user_id.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

we even tried before_save but it doesn’t seem like the model sees the change. Are we missing something obvious??

Comment: expected behaviour. When I update the user and remove user from a list. The callback is initiated and I can run some checks on the associated list

Comment: If a list belongs to a user, and then is removed, aren't you deleting the list? Why keep the list record if it doesn't belong to a user?

Comment: Without getting too deep into our business logic... lists belong to users but also have many users, when the owner removes a list (on purpose or accidentally) we wanted to switch the owner to another user

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to update the record? Because there are methods that DO NOT trigger callbacks like `update_column`, `update_attribute` and `update_all`

Comment: Using the plain .update method.... really thought this would touch the model but seems to ignore it